# How to get 'GET' param in controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying pass param in url but not able to get it in controller class.

```
.vue class
let url = "/getslots/{$day}";
```

routing file(web.php)

```
Route::get('/getslots/{day}', 'SlotController@getDay');
```

Controller class

```
  public function getDay($day){
    var_dump("Day: ".$day);
  }
```

I am not able to get the value in $day variable. Can anybody please help me to find the issue?

Comment: Have you ran either an `a href=" "` or a GET method form?

Comment: Use Request and  then you can do:  $request->day  or $request->input('day');

Comment: Have you a Day model ? if yes laravel will try to bind it, so try to change the name of parameter like `dayParam` and test it !!

Comment: Show us where is `day` coming from in js ?

Comment: Issue resolved. I just replace "/getslots/{$day}" with `/getslots/${day}`. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
        return 'User '.$id;
    });
```

Here you have example how to get GET parameter from url.
There is [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing) about.
Create url using concatenation of string create url `/getslots/ + this.day`